# C primer plus exercise 3-3 there is no beep

Tags: c

I know it's fairly simple code to do but I was just wondering if I was doing something wrong because I get no beep when I run the program.

I'm suppose to write a program that makes a beep and print

Startled by the sudden sound, Sally shouted,
"By the great Pumpkin, what was that!"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("\a");
printf("Startled by the sudden sound, Sally shouted,\n");
printf("\"By the Great Pumpkin, what was that\"\n");

return 0;
}
```

Any idea why there is no beep?

p.s. I'm on Linux by the way.

p.p.s. Why don't they give the answer to all the problems in their pdf? They only give answers to even number questions.

Comment: Perhaps your computer has the PC Speaker not plugged in ...

Comment: Is your terminal set up to produce beeps at all? Try `echo ^G` and/or `echo -e "\a"` (suggested by Wikipedia).

Comment: Nope, did not work. Do the beep comes from the regular speakers? If so they are working perfectly, I can listen to music.

Comment: Whether or not this works depends entirely on your platform and setup. It could be that your terminal is not configured to be able to produce beeps at all...